# DateTimePicker error does not show date

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having a problem with the component `DateTimePicker` it is not showing the date in windows 10, what could the problem be?

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you set an initial date on it?

Comment: Maybe a wrong date format? Are you using a custom format?

Comment: custom format may be causing that error. Show us that date time picker properties.

Comment: could you show the code you used to generate the datepicker and its properties ?

Comment: Default format can't really be wrong so its 99% sure a custom format that's doing this

Comment: I am not using custom format, they are in short format.

Comment: Image [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9b95feseq9848d/DateTime.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in my Form_Load()

```
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem.